# Web Speech Recognition on MediaStream

Tags: javascript, frontend, speech-recognition, mediastream, webspeech-api

Calling [`SpeechRecognition.start`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition/start) automatically requests microphone permission, but is there any way to start `SpeechRecognition` on a custom [`MediaStream`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream) (e.g. from [`getDisplayMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getDisplayMedia))?

Comment: I wish. I cannot find a way to do it.